# Flattening a matrix by specific size of mini matrices

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix, flatten

I want to flatten a M by N matrix in python.

```
H = [[1,3,0,1],[6,5,4,8],[1,1,1,1],[3,2,0,0]]
```

For this I need to choose a window size of s by t and flatten that windows first and move forward with the procedure until my windows covers all the M by N matrix.

lets say my s and t are 2.
so, I want to get:

```
H_flat = [1,3,6,5,0,1,4,8,1,1,3,2,1,1,0,0]
```

Is there a fast way for doing this with just a loop or without loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
res = []
for i in range(0, len(m), 2):
    res.extend(m[i][:2] + m[i + 1][:2] + m[i][2:] + m[i +1][2:])
print(res)
# [1, 3, 6, 5, 0, 1, 4, 8, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```